# Select only the value with mongoose in a Json document

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a Json document like this:

```
{"aaa": {"bbb": {"ccc": "YYYYY","ddd":"123"}}}
```

I want to return only the value "YYYYY". I am using mongoose module in node.js.
With this code i return:

```
{"aaa": {"bbb": {"ccc": "YYYYY"}}}
```

How can i remove the keys aaa,bbb,ccc?

```
.find()
.where('_id').equals('xxxxxxx')
.select({ _id: 0,'aaa.bbb.ccc': 1})
.exec( function(err, result) {

   return reply(result)
}
```

Comment: the question is not clear i guess this is why nobody answered yet... what you mean by remove keys?  If you want to return only few fields you need something like ```.select('field1 field2');``` is written here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

After getting the output:{"aaa": {"bbb": {"ccc": "YYYYY"}}} , try

```
var value=aaa.bbb.ccc;
```

it'll give you the desired output.